# Is Branch a timeline or a universe?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvels-what-if

In "What if...?" I learnt that you could have two timelines in one universe. Honestly, this only made me more confused with the MCU than I already am.

I don't know what is a timeline and what is a universe?
What the TVA used to prune, a timeline or a universe?

When Loki escaped with the space stone, did he go to a different timeline or a universe?

When branching started at the end of "Loki", were they timelines or universes?

What events cause a timeline split and what cause an alternative universe?

Comment: https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Timeline

Comment: @BCdotWEB I am not talking about Marvel Movies timeline (the release timeline), I am talking about the timeline concept in the movies and TV shows.

Comment: I don't know what Marvel MCU does, but usually a "branch off" is a new timeline that was made from another. So they may share "history" up until the point a "Y" is made in the timeline. Star Trek 2009 for instance makes an alternate parallel timeline when Nero (and eventually) Spock travel back in time to the day Kirk is born. However in that case there is also retro-casualty that results in some ripple effects happening before the entry point date. This is why Khan looks different, because he is modified from different gene set, which thematically juxtaposes him more with alter Spock.

Comment: In Fringe's case we get two parallel universe that are birthed together out of mitosis, but the show reveals that the these universes are inextricably linked by technology (wave syn cdevices) and have "started over" possibly millions of times, meaning there are several iterations of both universes' timelines. Fringe ends though with two possible branch off timelines as the past is reset and another character goes to the future to alter it, as there were people from the far future that came to occupy it, suggesting there may be several "reprints" of the season 4 timeline(s).

Comment: A timeline and a universe are normally synonymous. The distinction is that a universe is a contained "space" whereas a timeline is a set of events that can happen in a specific universe. When a timeline branches a new universe is created. What happens in Ep4 is that the Ancient One splits Doctor Strange so that 2 of him can live in one universe using 2 timelines.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot Thanks. You say "A timeline and a universe are normally synonymous", if that is true, then we can say that in ep4 Doctor Strange was in two universes in one timeline? Is that correct?

Comment: I wouldn’t say so. I just mean that normally the two are used interchangeably even if they don’t mean the same thing because normally the two events coincide. In the case of Ep4 the two aren’t the same.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot And that's why I am posting this question, these two concepts are confusing, and I don't clearly understand which means what, and when to expect which to occur.

Comment: See [Is there a difference between timelines and universes in the MCU?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/252230/25576) at scifi.